# how to cache in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, node-modules, memoizee

I am new to nodejs. I have one API which returns file in response. Currently when I get the request, I read the file every time and send it. Can we do caching in memory to speed up?

I checked this package. can we use this package to speed up.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee

```
 server.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(distFolder,'user','index.html'))
  });
```

**Current what I am doing**

Right now I am running node server.when `/user` request come on I am sending html file .while is working fine.

can we optimise this ? can we cache this file ?

Comment: you're sending a static file - what would you cache on the server?

Comment: You should look into the [HTTP caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) if you just send to a static file back.

Comment: @JaromandaX static file content

Comment: @JaromandaX can we set some header so that it file come from cache second request or other than first request

Comment: Oh, so you want to cache the file in memory so you don't have to read the file every time you send it - if on the other hand you're talking about client (browser) caching so the client doesn't need the response every time ... there is [this](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html) (I'm assuming you're using expressjs of course)

Comment: @JaromandaX..I am taking about this <<you want to cache the file in memory so you don't have to read the file every time you send it>>>

client will always send request but I need to send from cache

Comment: memoizing seems to be what you want then

Comment: can you please help me how we memoizing in node js . first request with from sendfile , rest req will be from memoizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach

```
import { readFileSync } from "node:fs";

const cache = {};
const simpleCache = path => {
    if (!cache[path]) {
        cache[path] = readFileSync(path).toString();
    }
    return cache[path];
};
server.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    res.send(simpleCache(path.join(distFolder,'user','index.html')));
});
```

Comment: sorry I understand the code .. but using above code it downloading file ..it is not showing anything on browser...
but when I was using this code `    res.sendFile(path.join(distFolder,'user','index.html'))
`. it is showing HTML content

Comment: I must've done something wrong then - probably the format of the data `readFileSync` gets is wrong ... perhaps you need `fs.readFileSync(path).toString()`

Comment: you did remember to import/require `fs`? right?

Comment: sorry still it downloading..not working I will try another solution

Comment: @naveen - that's odd, works for me like a bought one ... and ... you get no errors at all?

Comment: I am not getting error but if I am hitting `localhost:3000/user` --> it download the file with name `user`. content is there in file

Comment: so, it's getting a file, just not the right one?